# How to know if an input has been filled using JS

Tags: javascript, html-select

I was wondering if there is a way to know if an text input has been filled using JS

For example I have a basic text input :

```
<input type="text" name="textInput" id="form">
```

Here is the JS code I use to fill :

```
document.getElementById("form").value = "Some information";
```

And I'd like to know by any way if the input has been filled using JS to stop the sign-up for example. I have NO idea how to proceed.

Comment: In your example you show how to set a value, knowing how to do that, how would you get the value? Once you get the value how do you check a string to see if it’s empty? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could check if `defaultValue` property is different from the `value`:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("form")

input.value = "Some information";

const setWithJS = input.value !== input.defaultValue

alert(setWithJS)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textInput" id="form">
```

The idea here is that `defaultValue` will be set when HTML is initially parsed (value attribute). `defaultValue` will not reflect changes to value made programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can check this by using **if** condition that the field is filled or not

If(condition check){
Block of code
}